# Is there a way to disable the Internet Explore mode warning in Edge?

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have a legacy system that only works in IE. With the inevitable death of IE I'm testing it in IE mode in Edge and keep getting this banner:
[image]

It's annoying as I'm both aware of the fact I'm in IE mode and doing it for a reason as it doesn't work in normal Edge mode (or any other browser).

Comment: You may finally have to upgrade the legacy system to work with Chromium Edge (which supports a huge variety of systems).

Comment: @John Thanks for stating the bleeding obvious! It's on the list of things to do but is non-trivial and the sytem is business critical.

Comment: @Darren we still have a couple like that, too. Such a pain.

Comment: I found in [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies) MS Edge page reference to Enterprise Mode Site List. I followed the links a bit deeper, but that rabbithole is beyond my ken. Maybe there's something that's useful to you.

Comment: As long as you stay in Windows 10 (not 11) you will still have IE available, although you might need to use [How to Prevent Auto redirection from IE to Edge for unsupported sites](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/disable-auto-redirect-unsupported-sites-ie-to-edge/).

Comment: @Peregrino69, thanks. I can't see the option to stop the warning in there, but some useful stuff nonetheless.

Comment: @harrymc, ah that's good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you stay in Windows 10 (not 11) you will still have IE available,
although you might need to use
[How to Prevent Auto redirection from IE to Edge for unsupported sites](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/disable-auto-redirect-unsupported-sites-ie-to-edge/).

For compatibility's sake, even if you need to pass to Windows 11,
you may first create a virtual machine with Windows 10,
to do the testing on it.

Keeping virtual machines of older Windows versions is done by many
maintainers of deprecated software.

Comment: And now that is no longer true as user facing IE 11 is about to be removed from Windows 10 as of June 15, 2022. So IE Mode is the only work around.